# calculating triangle hypotenuse length from trapezoid

Tags: geometry

I was given this problem by a friend a few days ago, and I still haven't bee able to figure it out.

You are given a trapezoid **ABCD**, and a right triangle **ADE**, figure out the length of the line **AE**, from the lengths of the lines **AD** and **BC**. The angles **BCD**, **CDA**, and **ADE** are all right angles, and the sides of the trapezoid **AB** and **BC** are the same length.

[image: Here's a diagram of the problem]

I'm guessing my friend wants an equation in terms of **AE** = f(**AD**,**BC**). Please help me find the equation, I'm honestly stumped at this point :\ . Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From similarity of triangles EAD and EBC
$$\frac vy = \frac{v+x}x$$
hence
$$vx= vy + xy$$
$$v(x-y)= xy$$
and
$$v= \frac{xy}{x-y}=\cfrac 1{\cfrac 1y-\cfrac 1x}$$